# Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: selenium, protractor, webdriver-manager

I can run the selenium server with fresh rebooting of my Windows 7. However if I kill the server and start it again, I will get this error. Sometimes doing `webdriver-manager update--ignore_ssl` may fix the problem, but most of time it won't fix. Any idea?

I am running it on Windows 7 x64.

```
C:\Users\...> webdriver-manager start --ignore_ssl
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1084:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:606:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:436:38)
```

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time clearing cache and ignoring ssl during webdriver-manager update would solve the problem

```
npm cache clean
webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl
```

In my case I resolved by updating webdriver manage locally in the project and starting standalone server

> package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "webdrivermanager:update": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone=3.2.0 --ignore_ssl",
    "webdrivermanager:clean": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager clean",
    "install": "npm run webdrivermanager:clean && npm run webdrivermanager:update"
  }
```

> protractor configuration file

```
seleniumServerJar: 'node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.2.0.jar',
```

npm install update your webdriver-manager first time and everytime you need just issue the command protractor protractor.conf.js