# "unable to verify the first certificate" error when running "webdriver-manager update"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-manager

I have set http_proxy and https_proxy, also set system variables, but still get the following error when I tried to get the latest chrome driver and selenium server:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm>webdriver-manager update
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)
```

OS:win7 32bit

protractor:5.1.1

nodejs:6.10.2

java:1.7.79

npm:3.10.10

Comment: It's ok when I ran this last month in the same environment.

Comment: Update your question with NodeJS version and npm version. Also what version of Protractor, and Operating System.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy? Are you using webdriver-manager 12.0.4?

Comment: yes, but I have set system variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`. I am using the latest webdriver-manager 12.0.4.

Comment: Check my answer here...it would be helpful... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194545/error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain/43210674#43210674

Comment: @Jnawali Thanks, it works.

Comment: Glad that answer helped for you.